# JQuery Event.target problem in ie7

Tags: jquery, event-handling, internet-explorer-7

Trying to accses the class name from the event.target object.  Works in FF, Safari, and Chrome.  InternetExplorer 7 alerts "undefined".  Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("document").ready(function(){ 
  $(".page").hide();
  $(".page:first").show();
  $("#navBar a").bind("click", linkClicked);
 });
 function linkClicked(event){
   $("div.page:visible").fadeOut(250, function(){
    var $target = $(event.target);
    alert($target.attr("class"));
    //$("#" + $(event.target).attr("class")).fadeIn(250);
   }); 
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.  Set the event.target to a var before the callback for fade out. :p  any idea why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("document").ready(function(){ 
  $("#content").css("opacity","0.8");
  $(".page").hide();
  $(".page:first").show();
  $("#navBar a").bind("click", linkClicked);
 });
 function linkClicked(event){
  var $target = $(event.target);
  $("div.page:visible").fadeOut(250, function(){
   alert($target.attr("class"));
   //$("#" + $(event.target).attr("class")).fadeIn(250);
 });    
 }
</script>
```

Comment: My guess, once the fading animation starts, the IE7's DOM event handling screwed up (at least temporarily), hence it can't return the 'target' it is 'animating' then. Glad you found a work-a-round. Btw, do accept your own answer :P